# Replace with a regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Please see the SQL statement below:

```
select * from person1
inner join person2 on person1.reference=person2.reference
where replace(person1.surname,' ','')<>replace(person2.surname,' ','')
```

I want to join on reference and then list all persons with a different surname in person1 and person2.  However, I do not want whitespaces and certain other characters to be used in the matching, but I don't want lots of nested Replace statements like this:

```
replace(replace(replace(person1.surname,' ',''),char(39),''),'-','')<>replace(replace(replace(person2.surname,' ',''),char(39),''), '-','')
```

I am trying to design an SQL statements that replaces all characters that are not in the following list as a zero length string:

```
A-Z
a-z
Hyphen
```

I believe I could get around this using regular expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't have regex as an actual function.  You can do some fancy `PATINDEX` stuff though.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx

Comment: Maybe you should use a CLR UDF for that?

Comment: What is the real point of this replacement? What harm could `Bobby O'Brien` cause? What about `Sammy Garçia`? This sounds like a data cleansing problem that you should be solving long before you are performing joins. You can do this without RegEx, CLR etc. with a simple T-SQL UDF on both sides (which just loops through the string and rebuilds it with only the "valid" characters), but this will make your join slower than tree growth, because it has to be performed twice for every single row. A CLR UDF won't be much faster IMHO.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, thanks.  This is a data quality problem e.g. a user entering Ian 'O Bailey in person1 and Ian O Bailey in person2.  Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Like I said, this will be about as fast as tree growth, but have fun...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripBadCharacters
(
  @input NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(255), @i INT;

  SELECT @s = N'', @i = 0;
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@input)
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1) LIKE N'[A-Za-z-]'
    BEGIN
      SET @s = @s + SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1);
    END
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END

  RETURN (@s);
END
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(name1 NVARCHAR(255), name2 NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES('bob o''brien', 'bob obrien'); -- this will return
INSERT @x VALUES('bob obrien', 'bob o '' brien'); -- this will return
INSERT @x VALUES('bob o''brien', 'bob o''brian'); -- this will not

SELECT name1, name2 FROM @x 
  WHERE dbo.StripBadCharacters(name1) = dbo.StripBadCharacters(name2);
```

Comment: If we assume that usually there are more letters in a name than non-letter characters, `STUFF(@input, @i, PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z-]%', SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1)), '')` might turn out a tiny bit faster.

Comment: @AndriyM just like if I clean out my trunk I'll get a tiny bit better gas mileage? :-)

Comment: Something like that. :)

Comment: @Andriy M, are you able to provide an example as your answer looks very simple.

Comment: @w0051977: That's not a complete solution, just an illustration of a slightly different technique while keeping the same basic approach (going through the entire string character by character). That is, it would still require a loop and, as I said, the advantage, if any, over Aaron's solution would hardly be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

An inline table-valued function.  It's relatively snappy.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StringCompareAlpha(
  @str1 nvarchar(255), 
  @str2 nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
( 
  WITH
    t0 AS (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 0),
    t1 AS (SELECT 0 i FROM t0 a, t0 b),
    t2 AS (SELECT 0 i FROM t1 a, t1 b),
    t3 AS (SELECT 0 i FROM t2 a, t2 b),
    n  AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) i FROM t3),
    s1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i) i, SUBSTRING(@str1,i,1) c FROM n WHERE SUBSTRING(@str1,i,1) LIKE '[A-Za-z-]' AND i <= LEN(@str1)),
    s2 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i) i, SUBSTRING(@str2,i,1) c FROM n WHERE SUBSTRING(@str2,i,1) LIKE '[A-Za-z-]' AND i <= LEN(@str2))
  SELECT 1 i WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    (SELECT * FROM s1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM s2)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM s2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM s1)
  )
)
GO 

DECLARE @x TABLE(name1 NVARCHAR(255), name2 NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES('bob o''brien', 'bob obrien'); -- this will return
INSERT @x VALUES('bob obrien', 'bob o '' brien'); -- this will return
INSERT @x VALUES('bob o''brien', 'bob o''brian'); -- this will not

SELECT * FROM @x CROSS APPLY dbo.StringCompareAlpha(name1,name2)
```